# Error with passing this JSON with nested list of objects to a rest controller in spring

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

Please i am trying to pass this json to a controller in spring framework.

```
{
"date" : "2012-02-09",
"subject" : "Margin ",
"selections" : [ 
                    {"FGY" : ["Try", "Harder"]},{"LGY" : ["Harder", "Try"]}   
               ]
}
```

The Selections Class is

```
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.List;

    @Component
    public class Selections implements Serializable {

    //@Bean
    public Selections(){

    }

    @JsonProperty("FGY")
    private List<String> FGY;

    @JsonProperty("LGY")
    private List<String> LGY;

    public List<String> getFGY() {
        return FGY;
    }

    public void setFGY(List<String> FGY) {
        this.FGY = FGY;
    }

    public String getLGY(){
        return LGY;
    }

    public void setLGY(List<String> LGY) {
        this.LGY = LGY;
    }
}
```

The ReportRequest Class is :

```
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

   import java.io.Serializable;
   import java.util.Date;
   import java.util.List;

   @Component
   public class ReportRequest implements Serializable{

private String report;
private Date date;
private List<Selections> selections;

public ReportRequest(){

}

public String getReport() {
    return report;
}

public void setReport(String report) {
    this.report = report;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public List<Selections> getSelections() {
    return selections;
}

public void setSelections(List<Selections> selections) {
    this.selections = selections;
}
public ReportResponse processRequest() {

    for(Selections selection : getSelections()){ // null error occurs on either FGY or LGY depending on which is the second in the json list
        selection.getFGY().forEach(System.out::println); 
        selection.getLGY().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/request_report" , method = RequestMethod.POST )
public @ResponseBody
ReportResponse receive(@RequestBody ReportRequest reportRequest)  {
    return reportRequest.processRequest();
}
```

This is the error : java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Doing a debug i was able to find out that the null error occurs in the ReportRequest processRequest method.

OLD ERROR(SOLVED): The other attributes of the reportRequest object were properly initialized from the json but the attribute "selections" failed to initialize the "FGY" object with the list of strings in the json

EDIT(NEW ERROR): The new error is, only the first object in the selections list in the json is passed into the selections list in spring class ReportRequest. The second object in the list is not passed. Thus the null error occurs on whichever is second in the json. eg LGY is second presently.

StackTrace :

```
`   
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.teamapt.alm.utils.ReportRequest.processRequest(ReportRequest.java:79)
    at com.teamapt.alm.controller.AlmController.receive(AlmController.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.teamapt.alm.config.Config$1.doFilter(Config.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: please add the trace output.

Comment: Trace Added a requested

Comment: The edit was done to prevent asking the same question again. So a new error. Pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the getter/setter combo

```
public List<String> getFGY() {
    return FGY;
}

public void setFGY(List<String> FGY) {
    this.FGY = FGY;
}
```

Jackson (which I assume is what you are using for your JSON serialization/deserialization) will determine the property's name to be `fgy`, not `FGY`. Deserialization will therefore not find your property.

You can annotate either one with

```
@JsonProperty("FGY")
```

to explicitly set the property name you expect.

Comment: This worked. Appreciate this a lot. Never knew the case(lower or upper) could be the problem

Comment: @jibi I believe Jackson uses bean naming conventions by default.

Comment: @jibi Your first `Selections` element in the JSON array doesn't have a `LGY` value.

Comment: I does. this is the list of objects that make up the selections element

Comment: {"FGY" : ["Try", "Harder"]},{"LGY" : ["Harder", "Try"]}

Comment: @jibi No. That array contains two JSON objects. One that has FGY, but no LGY and one that has LGY, but no FGY.

Comment: Wow!!!! I did not notice that.  I am so sorry. Really appreciate your help today. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using @JsonIgnore in the child class on parents collection. It is trying to serialize recursively.

Follow this link for other ways to handle this.